# Class-dump-z extraction of classes & methods

Tags: ios, security, reverse-engineering

I am using class-dump-z for extracting all the class name & methods for reverse engineering of iOS apps.
But I want to know that how this application actually work.How this application managed to fetch the class name & methods related to that class.

Answer (score 0):

It's open source so you can view the code. Particularly this file https://github.com/nygard/class-dump/blob/master/Source/CDClassDump.m

The tool reads Mach-O files from a decrypted app which contain headers and a series of load commands. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O
[wiki Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O)